# Stamp duty on UK share purchases made by non-UK residents

Tags: united-kingdom, shares, european-union, tax-exemption, stamp-duty

I am a UK ex-pat living in the EU and have recently bought shares in two different UK companies using an EU-based broker. Following the transactions I was surprised to find that there was no stamp duty charged on either. Are no-UK residents exempt from stamp duty on stock market transactions?

Thank you in advance for your comments.